# fireEvent from iframe to top.document.body

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this function:

```
function doSomething(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    alert(e.type);
}
```

When the HTML (Master.html) page is ready, I'll call this other:

```
var iniciarTimeOut = function (e) {
    document.onload = doSomething;
    window.onmousedown = doSomething;
    window.onkeypress = doSomething;
};
```

I have an Iframe into Master.html and I want to detect the event into iframe.html but fire the event in Master.html I'm trying with this:

```
document.onmousedown = top.document.body.fireEvent("onload");
document.onkeypress = top.document.body.fireEvent("onmousedown");
document.onload = top.document.body.fireEvent("onload");
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is HTML5 using postMessage.

I found an example here:
http://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html

Comment: Here is a complete example of this implementation using postMessage to control TimeOut in Clien-Side http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?18578-How-To-Timeout-(Client-Side)-using-postMessage-(HTML5)-with-Countdown-alert&p=80171#post80171

Answer (score 0):

I would create a fictive event in your iframe and attach it to the the target link or frame.

As you may also notice, the way to fire events depends on the standards followed by the testing browser:

```
 // Attach the fictive event object to the target
    // MSIE
    if (document.createEventObject )
        YourTarget.fireEvent('onmouseup',oEvt) ;
    // W3C
    else
        YourTarget.dispatchEvent(oEvt) ;
```

Pls see more details [here](http://hornetbzz.developpez.com/tutoriels/javascript/dom/#L5-E-1-C)

Hope it helps or at least give you an hint as I'm not sure to fully understand your need.

Comment: Does not work... have the same result. What I need is run a code in master page but fired from iframe page.

Answer (score 0):

You can creat a wrapper fireevent method in the desired iframe and call windows fire event from that wrapper method.

Call this wrapper from any iframe other than this one. It will fire event on the desired iframe.

Comment: The probleme is i don't have all over the same page. That's why need postMessage.